# Why do I get the same results?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
    $all = $this->input->get('all');

    if($all)
    {
        $keywords = $this->input->get('search');
        $data['search'] = $keywords;
        $this->session->set_flashdata('search', $keywords);
        $query = "SELECT *  FROM `investOffers`, `news`";
        $counts = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM  `investOffers`, `news`";
        $first = false;
        if($keywords)
        {
            $data['keywords'] = $keywords;
            $this->session->set_flashdata('keywords', $keywords);
            $keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
            foreach($keywords as $k)
            {
                if(!$first)
                {
                    $query .= " WHERE investOffers.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR investOffers.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                    $query .= " OR news.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR news.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                    $counts .= " WHERE investOffers.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR investOffers.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                    $counts .= " OR news.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR news.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                    $first = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    $query .= " OR investOffers.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR investOffers.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                    $query .= " OR news.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR news.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                    $counts .= " OR investOffers.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR investOffers.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                    $counts .= " OR news.desc LIKE '% ".$k." %' OR news.title LIKE '% ".$k." %'";
                }
            }


        }
            $page = $this->uri->segment(2);
            if($page)
            {
                $query .= " ORDER BY investOffers.date DESC LIMIT ".$page.", 10";
                $counts .= " ORDER BY investOffers.date DESC LIMIT 10";
            }
            else
            {
                $query .= " ORDER BY investOffers.date DESC LIMIT 10";
                $counts .= " ORDER BY investOffers.date DESC LIMIT 10";
            }
        $data['query'] = $this->db->query($query);
        $counts = $this->db->query($counts);
        foreach($counts->result() as $q)
        {

        $count = $q->count;
        break;

        }
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/search';
        $config['prev_link'] = false;
        $config['next_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<strong><img src="'.IMAGE.'pagerArrow.png" class="pagerArrow" />';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</strong>';
        $from = intval($this->uri->segment(2));
        $config['per_page'] =  10;   
        $config['num_links'] = 5;    
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;  
        $config['total_rows'] = $count; 
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pager'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view(SITE.'search', $data, true);
        $this->load->view(SITE.'layout', $data);
        return true;

    }
```

so this is a search query, first we check if a search is "all", it means search by all the site, so then i make a array of keywords separated by whitespaces, entered in the form, so then i put it in a flash session for preg_match in the view, this is for preg_match highlighting text in the view of generated results, so then i make a concatenation of the query be adding more LIKE , so the problem is when i input 1 keyword, it gives me different results and its okey, but when i enter 2 or many keywords, it gives me the same results, i mean a list of result that are exact the same, i can't understand why is that, in the view its all okay, the problem is in this place of code, i have tried to set th DISTINCT keyword in the query, but it does not helped...

ps: this is codeigniter, MVC, this is a controller, i don't use models, because i don't want to open many files :)

Comment: Why don't you look at the generated query and see what's not right about it? That's too big of a wall of code to read through this late on a Friday.

Comment: First i see that your SQL statement is not right. You make a cross join of 2 tables but without join statement. What is relation between `investOffers` and `news` tables?

Comment: there is not relation, they are different tables, its a search for all the site, and where can i see the generated code and how can i see where is the problem?? i just want to generate all the results in one view

Comment: In this case you should use union state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your

```
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
```

is returning a length greater then 1. Since you are getting $keywords from a GET, it is possible that you need to urldecode your variable before passing it in the explode function.

```
$keywords = urldecode($keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should use [CI Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html). It does a lot of escaping to prevent something like [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I'm no security guru but I think your code is vulnerable. Beside, CI Active Record also has [Active Record Caching](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#caching) which will be useful in this case as you are using the same WHERE things for selecting and counting.

To debug, you can look at the last query by `echo $this->db->last_query();`

In your code, I notice that you left space before and after the keyword `"LIKE '% {$keyword} %'"`. Is that what you intended? I think your code will miss the case where the keyword is at the beginning or at the end of the subject. I think it could be the reason you're looking for.

Comment: i have done that because i wanted to get only a word, not a substring from a text, so ia have maked a left space and a right space, is there a way to find only full words, not a substring from a word in LIKE??

Comment: You should try query like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar REGEXP '[[:<:]]keyword_here[[:>:]]';` Besides, I don't think @user1418338 solution work. I believe that Input Class did urldecode for you. If you request something like `?key=foo+bar` then `($this->input->get('key') == 'foo bar') === TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is totaly wrong.
If you use

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```

You make a cross join between these 2 tables and the results are not right.
If You want to get results from more than one table with similar structures you should use UNION state instead:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2
```

If you want to use WHERE clause you may do it 2 ways:
1:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM (
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2) as tt
WHERE your where conditions
```

in this case you may order and limit results independent from table name

2:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
WHERE your where conditions
UNION
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2
WHERE your where conditions
```

This way you will take right results.
More info about UNION state you may get at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html